# In the Mix IDE how do I view tokens belonging to a user

Tags: tokens, mix

In the Mix IDE is it possible to view the tokens a user currently has in their account for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are not really stored in an "account". A token is just a contract that meets the API requirements set out by [EIP 20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20). Since the user's balance is stored in the contract and not in the user's account, you need to know the address of a token contract in order to check a balance.

Thus, if you add the token contracts to Mist, it will automatically display a user's balance, but it is generally not possible to enumerate all tokens which a user owns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation certainly makes sense, I've added the token contract to Mist and I'm interacting with it but where exactly would I see the tokens and the accounts they are assigned to?